# Make only specific area of UITableViewCell trigger cell selection

Tags: ios, uitableview, cocoa-touch

I have a fairly tall UITableViewCell with lots of labels and buttons on, and I only want a certain area that isn't covered in labels/buttons (roughly the top right quarter) to be the thing that triggers the cell's selection state (there will be a checkbox there and it'll be very clear to the user). I want to use the default `UITableViewCell` selection as it handle's the subview's backgrounds etc, as I need the tap state of the cell to show the whole cell as light blue.

I have tried putting a big button that does nothing behind my labels and buttons to "mask" an area out, and this works in some places where you are actually tapping on the button itself, however if you tap a label that has the button behind it, the cell still consumes that tap and the cell highlights. The tap doesn't go to the button in-between oddly.

How can I intercept the tap and make sure only within a certain region will the table view get that tap and trigger the cell highlighting?

Comment: Did you try, using selection = .none and handling the selection in your cell by yourself?

Comment: @ReinierMelian Yes, however as mentioned, I need to use the table view's default selection, which iterates over all subviews, sets label backgrounds to clear etc, so you can see the cell's selection view.

Comment: check my answer, test it and let me know @Sencha

Comment: @ReinierMelian Interesting approach, I'll test it out, fingers crossed — thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like you want to avoid `[UITableViewDelegate tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:]` being called when user taps on certain views in your cell. I would suggest achieving so by overriding `[UIView hitTest:withEvent:]` in your `UITableViewCell` subclass.
`[UIView hitTest:withEvent:]`'s default return value is defined as follow

> The view object that is the farthest descendent the current view and contains point. Returns nil if the point lies completely outside the receiver’s view hierarchy.

so by overriding it and returning an alternate `UIView` instance (an instances of your subviews) instead of the `UITableViewCell` instance, we can make the TableViewController believe that your are up to something else other than the `UITableViewCell` instance.

an example will be as follow (I've very limited knowledge of Swift. My applogies.):

```
- (UIView *)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
     // suppose you put all your subviews in contentView
    for (UIView *subview in self.contentView.subViews) {
        // translates the point relative to the subviews coordinate system.
        CGPoint convertedPoint = [self convertPoint:point toView:subview]; 
        // returns the subview instance if the touch happens inside the subview.
        if (CGRectContainsPoint(subview.bounds, convertedPoint)) { 
            return subview;
        }
    }
    // call the super's implementation if you find the touch didn't hit any sub view
    return [super hitTest:point withEvent:event]; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use a `UIButton` in the part that you need the selection action take place, and add this implementation in your cell must work as you need

**Example Code**

```
import UIKit

class OnlySelectablePartTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }
    //Action linked to the button for valid selection part of your cell
    @IBAction func selectionAction(_ sender: Any) {
        self.selectionStyle = .blue
        self.setSelected(!self.isSelected, animated: true)
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
        if(!selected)
        {
            self.selectionStyle = .none
        }
        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

}
```

Comment: @Sencha did you finally test my answer? please provide some feedback